# Power Bi: Embedding Report into MVC Site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerbi

I have created a power bi report. I want to embed this report to my MVC site. Here is my code:-

```
 private static readonly string ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"];
 private static readonly string ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
 private static readonly string RedirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"];
 private static readonly string AADAuthorityUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AADAuthorityUri"];
 private static readonly string PowerBiAPI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PowerBiAPI"];
 private static readonly string PowerBiDataset = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PowerBiDataset"];
 private static readonly string baseUri = PowerBiDataset;
 private static string accessToken = string.Empty;
 public class PBIReports
 {
     public PBIReport[] value { get; set; }
 }
 public class PBIReport
 {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string webUrl { get; set; }
     public string embedUrl { get; set; }
 }

 public ReportController()
 {
     try
     {
         if (Request.Params.Get("code") != null)
         {

             Session["AccessToken"] = GetAccessToken(
                 HttpContext.Request["code"],
                 ClientID,
                 ClientSecret,
                 RedirectUrl);
         }
         if (Session["AccessToken"] != null)
         {
             accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
             GetReport(0);
         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {

     }
 }

 public string GetAccessToken(string authorizationCode, string clientID, string clientSecret, string redirectUri)
 {      
     TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();
     string authority = AADAuthorityUri;
     AuthenticationContext AC = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TC);
     ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
     return AC.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
         authorizationCode,
         new Uri(redirectUri), cc).Result.AccessToken;
 }
 protected void GetReport(int index)
 {
     System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
         String.Format("{0}/Reports",
         baseUri)) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;

     request.Method = "GET";
     request.ContentLength = 0;
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
     using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
     {
         using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
             PBIReports Reports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PBIReports>(reader.ReadToEnd());
             if (Reports.value.Length > 0)
             {
                 var report = Reports.value[index];

                 ViewBag["ReportId"] = report.id;
                 ViewBag["EmbedUrl"] = report.embedUrl;
                 ViewBag["ReportName"] = report.name;
                 ViewBag["WebUrl"] = report.webUrl;
             }
         }
     }
 }

 public void GetAuthorizationCode()
 {
     var @params = new NameValueCollection
     {
         {"response_type", "code"},
         {"client_id", ClientID},
         {"resource", PowerBiAPI},
         { "redirect_uri", RedirectUrl}
     };

     var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
     queryString.Add(@params);
     Response.Redirect(String.Format(AADAuthorityUri + "?{0}", queryString));
 }

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     GetAuthorizationCode();
     return View();
 }
```

On Redirecting to "Report Page", it goes for power bi login page and after I sign in it redirects back to this page (as homepage and redirect url are same). But `Request.Params.Get("code") != null` is null. `HttpContext.Request` is also null. Why? Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906078/embedding-power-bi-report-promise-is-not-defined-powerbi-js

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of a controller you don't have the `this.HttpContext` object to your disposal yet. You might have `HttpContext.Current`, but I am not sure of that.

What you should do is move that code to an action (for example your `GetReport` action), where you can make your checks.

Comment: How would I manage my redirection If i move my code to getreport. It will be confused in loop only,

Comment: What redirect do you mean?

Comment: If user navigates to this page then if access token is not available then it will go for signin after signing in, it will redirect to same url with code=accesstoken in query string and now I want to read the value from query string and generate access token using this and then get report will be called.

Comment: I tried to move the code to `GetReport()` it didn't worked.

Comment: That is not my fault. I told you the reason why your current code doesn't work. If the code is actually that broken you have a new problem, I can't help that. Post a new question with a clear problem statement, the error message, etc.

Comment: I have updated my code. Now that Request object is available.